# How to get number with regex without leading 0

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I want to get a number in a string and display this number without leading "0".

If I do this:

```
"--- 01 ---" -replace ".*(\d\d).*", "Number `$1"
```

I get

```
Number 01
```

I don't know to remove leading 0 with a regex. Then I convert the found number in int.
But if I do this

```
"--- 01 ---" -replace ".*(\d\d).*", "Number $([int]$1)"
```

I get

```
Number 0
```

and not

```
Number 1
```

Why ? How can I remove leading 0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
"--- 01 ---" -replace ".*?0*(\d+).*", "Number `$1"
```

because you can use it with big numbers.

You can test with [this link](http://regex101.com/r/cR3gJ5/1)

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\d\d)` specifies that there are two digits in your string. You can specify `0(\d)` instead to specify that there's a 0 and one digit after it.

In your example, the final PS would be something like this:

```
"--- 01 ---" -replace ".*0(\d).*", "Number `$1"
```